# Cray XE6 parallel tasks / parallel tasks per node

Tags: parallel-processing, job-scheduling, cray

In a job submission script (Cray XE6) what is the difference between 'number of parallel tasks' (-n) and 'number of parallel tasks per node' (-N)?

Answer (score 2):

Im inexperienced in this but some googling gave:

[It looks like a MPI parameter in an example:](http://www.prace-project.eu/Best-Practice-Guide-Cray-XE-HTML?lang=en#sec-5.2)

```
# Launch the parallel job using aprun.
# Run the executable my_mpi_executable.x using total
# of 2048 parallel tasks, with 32 tasks assigned per node.
aprun -n 2048 -N 32 ./my_mpi_executable.x arg1 arg2
```

[From Cray Brochure:](http://www.cray.com/Assets/PDF/products/xe/CrayXE6Brochure.pdf)

Each Cray XE6 blade includes four compute nodes for high 
scalability in a small footprint – up to 128 processor cores per 
blade or 3,072 processor cores per cabinet. **Each compute node 
has two AMD Opteron™ 6300 Series processors (16 cores) coupled** 
with its own memory and Gemini communication interface and is 
designed to efficiently run up to **32 MPI tasks**. Alternately, it can 
be programmed to run OpenMP within a compute node and MPI 
between nodes.

From the info above, n can be up to 3072 for a full cabinet and N can be 32 for two opterons(6300 series).

Answer (score 2):

A `man aprun` will solve all your questions for that.

`-n` means how many instances of your executable you want (for MPI, this means how many MPI processes you want).

`-N` means how many instances per node you want.

`-d` is the depth, i.e how many threads per instance.